# GroupBy + custom aggregation on Dataset with Case class / Trait in the Key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to refactor some code and put the general logic into a trait. I basically want to process datasets, group them by some key and aggregate:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.sql.{ Dataset, Encoder, Encoders, TypedColumn }

case class SomeKey(a: String, b: Boolean)

case class InputRow(
 SomeKey,
 v: Double
)

trait MyTrait {

  def processInputs: Dataset[InputRow]

  def groupAndAggregate(
    logs: Dataset[InputRow]
  ): Dataset[(SomeKey, Long)] = {
    import logs.sparkSession.implicits._

    logs
      .groupByKey(i => i.key)
      .agg(someAggFunc)

  }
  //Whatever agg function: here, it counts the number of v that are >= 0.5
  def someAggFunc: TypedColumn[InputRow, Long] =
    new Aggregator[
      /*input type*/ InputRow,
      /* "buffer" type */ Long,
      /* output type */ Long
    ] with Serializable {

      def zero = 0L

      def reduce(b: Long, a: InputRow) = {
        if (a.v >= 0.5)
          b + 1
        else
          b
      }

      def merge(b1: Long, b2: Long) =
        b1 + b2

      // map buffer to output type
      def finish(b: Long) = b
      def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Long] = Encoders.scalaLong
      def outputEncoder: Encoder[Long] = Encoders.scalaLong
    }.toColumn
}
```

everything works fine: I can instantiate a class that inherits from MyTrait and override the way I process inputs:

```
import spark.implicits._
case class MyTraitTest(testDf: DataFrame) extends MyTrait {
    override def processInputs: Dataset[InputRow] = {
      val ds = testDf
        .select(
          $"a",
          $"b",
          $"v",
        )
        .rdd
        .map(
          r =>
            InputRow(
              SomeKey(r.getAs[String]("a"), r.getAs[Boolean]("b")),
              r.getAs[Double]("v")
          )
        )
        .toDS
      ds
    }
val df: DataFrame = Seq(
 ("1", false, 0.40),
 ("1", false, 0.54),
 ("0", true, 0.85),
 ("1", true, 0.39)
).toDF("a", "b", "v")

val myTraitTest  = MyTraitTest(df)
val ds: Dataset[InputRow] = myTraitTest.processInputs
val res                   = myTraitTest.groupAndAggregate(ds)
res.show(false)

+----------+----------------------------------+
|key       |InputRow                          |
+----------+----------------------------------+
|[1, false]|1                                 |
|[0, true] |1                                 |
|[1, true] |0                                 |
+----------+----------------------------------+
```

Now the problem: I want SomeKey to derive from a more generic trait Key, because the key will not always have only two fields, the fields won't have the same type etc. It will always be a simple tuple of some basic primitive types though.

So I tried to do the following:

```
trait Key extends Product
case class SomeKey(a: String, b: Boolean) extends Key
case class SomeOtherKey(x: Int, y: Boolean, z: String) extends Key

case class InputRow[T <: Key](
   key: T,
   v: Double
)

trait MyTrait[T <: Key] {

  def processInputs: Dataset[InputRow[T]]

  def groupAndAggregate(
    logs: Dataset[InputRow[T]]
  ): Dataset[(T, Long)] = {
    import logs.sparkSession.implicits._

    logs
      .groupByKey(i => i.key)
      .agg(someAggFunc)

  }

  def someAggFunc: TypedColumn[InputRow[T], Long] = {...}
```

I now do:

```
case class MyTraitTest(testDf: DataFrame) extends MyTrait[SomeKey] {
    override def processInputs: Dataset[InputRow[SomeKey]] = {
      ...
    }
```

etc.

But now I get the error : `Unable to find encoder for type T. An implicit Encoder[T] is needed to store T instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
      .groupByKey(i => i.key)`

I really don't know how to work around this issue, I tried lots of things without success. Sorry for this quite lengthy description but hopefully you have all the elements to help me understand... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark needs to be able to implicitly create the encoder for product type T so you'll need to help it work around the JVM type erasure and pass the TypeTag for T as an implicit parameter of your groupAndAggregate method.

A working example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.sql.{ DataFrame, Dataset, Encoders, TypedColumn }
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

trait Key extends Product
case class SomeKey(a: String, b: Boolean) extends Key
case class SomeOtherKey(x: Int, y: Boolean, z: String) extends Key

case class InputRow[T <: Key](key: T, v: Double)

trait MyTrait[T <: Key] {

  def processInputs: Dataset[InputRow[T]]

  def groupAndAggregate(
    logs: Dataset[InputRow[T]]
  )(implicit tTypeTag: TypeTag[T]): Dataset[(T, Long)] = {
    import logs.sparkSession.implicits._

    logs
      .groupByKey(i => i.key)
      .agg(someAggFunc)
  }

  def someAggFunc: TypedColumn[InputRow[T], Long] =
    new Aggregator[InputRow[T], Long, Long] with Serializable {

      def reduce(b: Long, a: InputRow[T]) = b + (a.v * 100).toLong

      def merge(b1: Long, b2: Long) = b1 + b2

      def zero = 0L
      def finish(b: Long) = b      
      def bufferEncoder = Encoders.scalaLong
      def outputEncoder = Encoders.scalaLong
    }.toColumn
}
```

with a wrapping case class

```
case class MyTraitTest(testDf: DataFrame) extends MyTrait[SomeKey] {
    import testDf.sparkSession.implicits._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct

    override def processInputs = testDf
        .select(struct($"a", $"b") as "key", $"v" )
        .as[InputRow[SomeKey]]
}
```

and a test execution

```
val df = Seq(
 ("1", false, 0.40),
 ("1", false, 0.54),
 ("0", true, 0.85),
 ("1", true, 0.39)
).toDF("a", "b", "v")

val myTraitTest  = MyTraitTest(df)
val ds = myTraitTest.processInputs
val res = myTraitTest.groupAndAggregate(ds)
res.show(false)

+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
|key       |$anon$1($line5460910223.$read$$iw$$iw$InputRow)|
+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
|[1, false]|94                                             |
|[1, true] |39                                             |
|[0, true] |85                                             |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
```